Save renamed active MS-Word document on SharePoint & OneDrive
Word templates have been using a suite of custom macros for the past few years.
We started using SharePoint and OneDrive. All macros continue to function as normal, except for 1. This macro is supposed to save a backup file of the active Word document with the current date and time.
Unlike the other macros, which only make edits to the formatting of the document, this externally alters the file. I suspect this may be a security or trust-center issue.
Is there anything in the coding that could causing an issue on SharePoint?
' Create a timestamped backup copy of current document
' Saves to Archive folder in filepath of current document
' Creates Archive folder if one does not exist
'
Dim wordDoc As Document
Dim FSO As Object
Dim backupFile As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileExt As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim sourcePath As String
Dim timeStamp As String

Set wordDoc = ActiveDocument
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filePath = wordDoc.path
If filePath = "" Then GoTo LeaveSub
If InStr(filePath, "/") Then filePath = convertPath(filePath)
sourcePath = wordDoc.FullName
If InStr(sourcePath, "/") Then sourcePath = convertPath(sourcePath)

fileName = Left(wordDoc.Name, (InStrRev(wordDoc.Name, ".") - 1))
timeStamp = Format(Now, "--yyyy-mm-dd--hhmm")
fileExt = Right(wordDoc.Name, Len(wordDoc.Name) - InStrRev(wordDoc.Name, "."))

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
If Not FSO.FolderExists(filePath & "\_Archive") Then FSO.CreateFolder (filePath & "\_Archive")
ActiveDocument.Save
backupFile = filePath & "\_Archive\" & fileName & timeStamp & "." & fileExt
FSO.CopyFile sourcePath, backupFile
On Error GoTo 0

If Dir(backupFile) <> "" Then
    MsgBox "A backup of " & wordDoc.Name & " was created on " & Format(Now, "yyyy-Mmm-dd at hh:mm"), vbOKOnly, "Backup File Saved Successfully"
Else
    MsgBox "The backup directory could not be found. Please make sure the document is no in Read-Only mode and try again.", vbOKOnly, "Error with Backup"
End If

LeaveSub:
Set FSO = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrorHandle:
MsgBox "There was an error with creating a backup for " & wordDoc.Name & ". Please make sure you have permissions to edit the source file.", vbExclamation, "Backup File Saved Successfully"
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub

I manually created a folder called "Archive" to see if the macro was struggling to create a folder location for the backup file, but the macro still returned an error message:

There was an error with creating a backup for ~Word Document's Name~. Please make sure you have permissions to edit the source file.

This is the error text at the end of the VBA code so I don't know if it's truly a permission issue.
The macro works when the Word document is saved on a local folder/desktop but not when saved on SharePoint or OneDrive.

"still returned an error message" -- and what was that message?

"There was an error with creating a backup for ~Word Document's Name~. Please make sure you have permissions to edit the source file."
But this is the error text at the end of the VBA code so I don't know if it's truly a permission issue.

What did you do to rule out it being a permissions issue?

Please edit your question to include relevant error messages in the text of the question (rather than in a comment).

RE: Permission - I asked IT to create a test sharepoint site for me, giving me full access to the folder. Also , I created the word document myself so I have full control/permission of the document (unless i'm mistaken and there's another step i'm missing).

Is the file path an http: or https: address? If so, not sure FileSystemObject will be able to make a copy. If the address is a local hard disk address (e.g. of a document stored in a local copy of the User's OneDrive) it might work. Worth having a look at that general area as you might need to rethink how you make your backups.

The file path is indeed https: - whereas we never had issues when the filepath was http:.
Is it possible to swap out FSO for something else? or would i need to re-think the entire process for an https file path?

FSO only works for local/network folders: it doesn't work for HTTP or HTTPS paths.  If the folder where the document is located is synced locally then you have more options, otherwise it's a bit of work to interact directly with SharePoint.  If you don't need to create the _Archive folder then you could likely work around Word's lack of SaveCopyAs and save the timestamped copy directly to SP.

Nb SharePoint/OneDrive have built-in file versioning features which may be enough for your needs.

@TimWilliams Oddly enough, FSO worked with our HTTP file paths so I think I was a little hopeful. I'll explore an option that doesn't require the Archive folder. Thanks!

@jonsson I can definitely explore that as an option, thanks!

I'm surprised to hear FSO worked with HTTP paths...
